# Java Greyscale buffered image

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, grayscale

So I have a byte array representing pixel data (8bit grayscale). No header. No nothing. Just the data. I want to create a buffered image from this data. I did

```
image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
image.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, w, h, data);
this.x = w;
this.y = h;
scalemode=false;
exactmode=true;
```

where w is just width in pixel,h is height in pixel,data is the byte array and image is BufferedImage

here is my paint method

```
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        int rx = (this.getWidth() - x) / 2;
        int ry = (this.getHeight() - y) / 2;

        g2d.drawImage(image, rx, ry,x,y, null);
    }
```

I, however, get this image (the real image is a fingerprint, which is mostly white pixel)

[image: messed up image]

What went wrong? I tried saving the data as is and then viewing it in Photoshop. The data is fine.

[edit]
Never mind this problem. I fucked up in other part of the code and was not aware. Thank you for all inputs though

Comment: What type is `data`?

Comment: data is byte[] 1byte = 1pixel

Comment: draw every byte on each pixel...

Comment: Is that 1 pixel border part of the image?

Comment: no border is not the part of the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what is wrong, as you haven't posted enough information. We don't know `w`, `h` or what information is in your `data`. We don't know what the image *should* look like.

However, here's some code that does pretty much exactly what you are doing, and it works for me:

```
// Set up h/w and backing data
int w = 300;
int h = 200;
byte[] data = new byte[w * h];

// Create a smooth gradient
for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    int off = y * w;

    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        data[off + x] = (byte) (Math.round((x / (double) w) * 127) 
                              + Math.round((y / (double) h) * 127));
    }
}

// Create BufferedImage from data
final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
image.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, w, h, data);

// Show it all in a window
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(getClass().getSimpleName());
        frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Here is the result:

[image: Image of JFrame from above code]

Comment: the image provided by Green Melon really looks like it has incorrect values for width and height..

Comment: I just tried testing the whole thing, and I found that if the image is created in a nice single main thread, the image is fine. However, when I created the image in mouse event listener thread, the image becomes garbled! I just realized that the data (the byte array) is already messed up so there is no way I can get it right. Do you know what might be the problem in reading from BufferedinputStream from listener thread? I used the code from [here](https://github.com/mellongreen/ZFM20Module/blob/master/ZFM20Module.java). Particularly, the upImg  method

Comment: @GreenMellon Ok. No problem. :-) Reading from streams should work just as normal from the listener thread, but for the sake of a responsive UI it is strongly discouraged. Generally, all I/O should be done on a background thread. Anyway, glad you figured it out!

Comment: Turned out that the fingerprinting module I was working with actually modify its image buffer when it convert image to signature file. I am totally lost as to why (small memory?). So it had nothing to do with Java. Thanks for the tip though

Answer (score 1):

draw every byte on each pixel...

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
for (int dy = 0; dy < h; dy ++){
    for(int dx = 0; dx < w; dx ++){
        int index = dy*w + dx;
        int rgb = data[index];
        rgb = rgb << 24 & 0xFFFF; //BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY consideres only the red-channel;
        //rgb = 00 data[index] FF FF
        image.setRGB(dx,dy,rgb);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you didn't set up your Buffer properly...

```
byte[] data = ... 
DataBufferByte db = new DataBufferByte(data, w*h);
image.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, w, h, db );
```

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html#setDataElements%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29

Comment: The method you are looking for is [setDataElements(x, y, w, h, data)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html#setDataElements%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29). And to quote the docs: "Sets the data for a rectangle of pixels from a *primitive array* of type TransferType" (emphasis mine). This answer is clearly incorrect. The OP's code is fine in this regard.

Comment: @haraldK yes, read on and you'll find " For image data supported by the Java 2D API, this will be one of DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT, DataBuffer.TYPE_INT, DataBuffer.TYPE_SHORT, DataBuffer.TYPE_FLOAT, or DataBuffer.TYPE_DOUBLE"... so where's the error?

Comment: You seem to think that `DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE` == `DataBufferByte`. It isn't. A "*primitive array* of type `DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE`" simply means  `byte[]`.

Comment: well, no that's now what i was thinking ^ ^ (DataBufferByte.getType() would return DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE - but that's leading to no-where)...i'll aprechiate your example and accept that your code is working. As mentioned in an comment in your example i guess the OP has merely problems with not knowing width/height... @haraldK thanks for providing a good example...

Comment: I think so too. That is why I ask about the border. And for the record, your code above will crash at runtime, with the following exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.awt.image.DataBufferByte cannot be cast to [B`. ;-)

Comment: thank you for pointing that out - i'll leave this answer as a bad example, on how to NOT do it ^^ great work there @haraldK